# Scrollview does not go behind the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have implemented a scrollview and for reason I can't figure out why, my Navigation Bar has disappeared in the simulator.  If anyone has any experience with this please help me to figure out what is happening.  Thank you for viewing

Comment: Would be useful to know a bit more about your implementation; is it all in a storyboard? Do you have a view controller embedded in a navigation etc? Do you do everything in code?

Comment: Post the code, please.

Comment: @DanSpag I selected all of the elements in embedded in a scrollview in the storyboard.  I will post the viewcontroller.m code.

Comment: [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; Rings any bell?

Comment: Oh wow.  I don't know how that got in there, so embarrassing

Comment: Please post *relevant* code. No one is going to go through all your code to find the juicy bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

in your viewWillAppear: this hides the navigation bar.

And you are doing:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: The dangers of cutting and pasting code it seems.  This line belongs in another VC